# How to use session and redirect with facebook og properties

Tags: php, facebook

I would like to share a page with image on facebook. I used below code and it is working perfectly fine for static images.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
  xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

<head>
<title>MyExample</title>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
<meta property="og:title" content="This is my example"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://mywebsite.com/mypage.php"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://mywebsite.com/images/myimage.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Mywebsite"/>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

The image name I am passing here is static one. How I can provide dynamic image to this page? Can I use php session? How?
Also, if anyone clicks on my post, I would like to redirect user to another url. How I can do that?

Comment: You would need to use a server side language such as php to change the image. I'd recommend you read up on php first and attempt this yourself. Then others will help you if you're struggling, but people won't generally code this solution for you. Especially as we don't know exactly how you define this dynamic image e.g is it from a database, do you have a list somewhere in a specific folder etc.

Comment: No, sessions are the wrong thing to use here. Use a GET parameter. And redirecting human visitors elsewhere is done easiest via Javacript. (You could do a server-side redirect as well, but then you would have to implement an exception for the FB scraper.)

Answer (score 0):

pass the dynamic data form your controller to view and print that data in your meta properties

Comment: <meta property="og:title" content="<?= $title; ?>">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://mywebsite.com/images/<?= $image;?>">

Comment: I am creating that image through other script (script does some operations on the image) and I want to pass it to this file. That image(processed) is not stored anywhere. Can I pass it directly after processing?